# quickest way to make clickable imagemap of the US

Tags: javascript, imagemap

what is the quickest way to make clickable imagemap of the US? Is there any jquery plugin available for this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean clickable? Selectable points on the map? A link to another resource?

Answer (score 4):

My plugin, that offers some features different from the others mentioned: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster

But generally speaking if all you want is a "clickable map" you don't even need jQuery - just use an HTML image map, and bind a click event to an `area`. But using the plugin offers feature like area highlighting/selection/grouping and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this jQuery plugin: http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/

Answer (score 2):

I created a mapping solution using SVG and jQuery which is accessible at

[Makeaclickablemap](http://www.makeaclickablemap.com).

Creating and saving a clickable US map is free, but it is also possible to commit edits later and there are also many other maps available.

Answer (score 1):

Just use one of "image map generators" there are a lot of them in the internet. You don't even need JS for that. Here is the link to one of them: http://www.image-maps.com

Answer (score 1):

Hi found the thing i was looking for here - [Using JQuery hover with HTML image map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745110/using-jquery-hover-with-html-image-map)

thanks :)