# Image with links in certain areas in HTML 5 for mobile

Tags: javascript, image, ionic-framework, regions

[image: Image of the app]

I'm developing a mobile app with ionic, and in the index page I want to make the regions of an image clickable, like links. How can I do that? Is there a way to do that in Javascript? Or a tool to define the clickable regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_area_coords.asp

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I have the img with a width="100%" attribute, Can I define areas too?

Comment: It doesn't, however [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13322059/3624196) shows you how you can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an image map, which is what [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) is for. In your case you would add `<area shape="circle" coords="x,y,r"... />` for your circles, where `x,y` are the x and y coordinates and `r` is the radius. There are even tools to define your own image map [for example](http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/).

Note that to connect the `<map>` with your `<img>` by using `usemap="#myImageMap"` where `myImageMap` is the `name` on your `map`:

```
<img src="myImage.png" .. usemap="#myImageMap">
<map name="myImageMap">
    <area shape="circle" ... />
    ...
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML tag `map` is designed exactly for this. Use `href="javascript:onClick()"` for JS calls instead of navigation.

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
    <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
    <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

MDN has a good specification of the `area` tag - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<map>` and `<area>`.
But It can be not working on some devices and browsers.
Then you can solve that problem through [jQuery image map alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190543/jquery-image-map-alternative)

Comment: Image maps `<map>` are standard, and have [wide support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map#Browser_compatibility) among browsers.