# Best way to create a custom contact us map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a map with different regions. When regions are rolled over that region lights up and links to that specific region.

Is it best to use HTML image map?

Comment: By map, do you mean geographical map?  Or map of areas on an image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/745110/901048

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best" is a highly relative concept, in this case.

HTML image maps are considered 'deprecated' by many developers, even though they're not. While CSS-positioned overlays works well, and sometimes better, with rectangular regions, image maps are uniquely suited for dealing with circular and/or polygonal areas.

However, if you want the image to 'light up' when you mouse over a particular area, you have a tricky problem. Certainly it's possible to approach this with only images and CSS/JavaScript -- I wrote a jQuery plugin to automate this process for a job last year -- but other plugins exist that handle it using SVG/Canvas graphics.

The leading plugin is [here](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/).