# How to divide TD cell logically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have HTML table cell (TD) with a background image. Left half of cell has one bg color, right half another color. Now I'd like to divide this cell logically; when I click (or mouseover) the left half of this cell to have one functionality and when click (or mouseover) the right half of the same cell to have another functionality. How to achieve this logically dividing of the same cell? I'd like to avoid two DIV (or similar) elements inside cell and to achieve this only over existing TD cell element.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with an image map (similar SO question here [Using JQuery hover with HTML image map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745110/using-jquery-hover-with-html-image-map)) but in my opinion it is easier with 2 images and divs.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not acceptable for me. When I said in my question that I want to avoid DIV subelements inside TD that assumed that I want to avoid other even more complex subelements. In my table (hotel booking calendar) I have more hundreds of TD elements so I need more efficient solution.

Comment: I see. If the cells have fixed size you could get the (x,y) position of the mouse click and determine if it's on the right half or left half (I'm not sure if it's feasible for the mouse over).