# Unable to display multiple tooltips on a single image

Tags: jquery, html, imagemap

pardon my code for redundancy...I was trying to create popup images which contains some button controls inside it using jquery.

Here is what i tried so far:
CSS code:

> button.button
>               {
>                  color: #fff; background: #000;
>                   font-size: .8em;
>                   font-weight:bold;
>                   font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
>                   border: solid 1px #ffcf31; 
>               } 
>   .tooltip{ 
>       background:transparent url(~/Box.png);
>                   display:none;
>                   height:180px;
>                   padding:0px 0px 10px 30px; 
>                   width:320px;
>                   font-size:14px;
>                   color:#000;
>                   overflow:auto;
>                   border:2px solid black;
>               }

Javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Harmful_id").tooltip({
            offset: [10, 2],
            effect: 'slide'
        });
    });
    function replyclick(a) {
        var e = document.getElementById(a);
        if (!e) return true;
        if (e.style.display == "none") {
            e.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            e.style.display = "none"
        }
        return true;
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<img id="continuum" src= "~/abc.png" alt="" usemap="#JQTooltip" style="width: 766px; height: 397px; border:0px"/>
    <map id="JQTooltip_map" name="JQTooltip">
    <area shape="rect" id="Harmful_id" coords="98,158,189,215" href="#" alt="" title=""/></map><div class="tooltip">
     <button type="button" class="button" id="btn1" onclick="replyclick('view1');"><b>1.</b></button><b onclick="replyclick('view1');"><u>Definition</u></b><div id="view1" style="display:none">Bla bla bla</div>
```

This works for only 1 part of the image map i.e coords="98,158,189,215". I would like to map for other co-ordinates as well on the same image.

I want to know what changes should I make to accomodate mapping other co-ordinates!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this answer:

[Using JQuery hover with HTML image map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745110/using-jquery-hover-with-html-image-map)

Specifically, this plugin looks to be very robust and have a lot of cool features:

[Image Mapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)