# maparea OnMouseOver show image

Tags: php, javascript, html, helper

I have a travel website. I use multiple clickable maps. Everything works fine but instead of the title coming up onmouseover, I would like a image to show up (flag of the region). I use a php framework butr that should not be a problem, although I have tried many versions of the this.src and others I still can't get it to work.

Code:

> ```
> <img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/world.jpg" height="412" width="940" alt="Worldmap" title="Worldmap" usemap="#worldmap"/>
> <map name="worldmap">
> <area shape="poly" coords="522, ... 494, 120" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/regions/africa" alt="Africa" onmouseover="this.src='assets/images/1.jpg';" />
> ```

See: http://www.holidaysrating.com/index.php/topmenu/worldmap
Can someone help?

Comment: Please take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745110/using-jquery-hover-with-html-image-map

Comment: I tried that but does not really work..