# How to add a pop up display to image map coords?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I would like to have pop ups with information on my image map coords. I have the image map set up and working fine but I can't seem to incorporate a pop up whether it be jQuery or just  with CSS.

An example image map coord line is:

`<area shape="rect" coords="2,44,250,108" href="http://blah.com" alt="test alt" title="test title"    />`

I tried putting that code into

```
<span class="dropt" title="title">Above area shape line here
<span style="width:500px;">Pop-up text</span>
</span>
```

with the css but didn't work.

I also tried the jQuery and got the pop up to work on text and single image, but is it possible to do it using image map coords?

Thanks,

Comment: [Found same post with the answers in StackOverflow.][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745110/using-jquery-hover-with-html-image-map

Answer (score 0):

Go to your area and change your href="http://blah.com" to either javascript:alert('hello')" or "javascript:openPopup()" or whatever that suits you, on the openPopup u have to define a script for that first.

Comment: Hi Jason, Welcome to SO. this is a very old question, try checking the dates before putting in a answer. Cheers

Comment: opps sorry didn't saw that my bad