# How to show a dropdown when you hover over a specific area an on image? (HTML, CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dropdown

Is it possible to show a dropdown whenever you hover over some specific area on an image? For example, if my mouse is within 50,62 and 70,80. I already tried this with invisible boxes and divs, but the only way I could get them to overlay the image was with position properties, but they wouldn't stay in place if I reshaped or resized the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code which is not working for you?

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/745110/691711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/v8dp91jL/12/

The code is pretty self-explanatory.
Just two imp things:

1. Everything should be in %
2. the `.dropdown` is inside `.hover-area` so that when you move your mouse from `.hover-area` to `.dropdown`, `.dropdown` doesn't disappear because it is still technically inside `.hover-area` even tho it's visually not

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for taking your time to help me out. ^w^

Comment: @Alexandria You're welcome! :D Also you are really sweet ^_^ xD

Answer (score 0):

You can add some hidden element (`span`) positioned on some specific area and it is going to trigger the hover:

HTML:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <span class="image-hover-trigger"></span>
    <img src="..." >
    <div class="dropdown"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-wrapper { position: relative; }
.image-hover-trigger { position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 20%; right: 20%; bottom: 20%; }
.dropdown { display: none; }
.image-hover-trigger:hover ~ .dropdown { display: block; }
```